# ActiveRecord :has_many and includes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, has-many

I am using rails 4.2.0 - this are my Models:

```
class Customer < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :meters, -> { includes :contracts }
end

class Meter < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :customer
  has_many :contracts
end

class Contract < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :meter
end
```

Now, I want to display all Contracts of an Customer. According to the [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-many-association-reference) I should be able to do this:

```
@customer.meters.contracts
```

However, it doesn't work. This is the error message:

```
undefined method `contracts' for #<Meter::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007fb0385730b0>
```

What is the best approach in this situation?
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Each model class, as in your example, represents just one of those instances of a database record i.e. your `Meter` class represents just one `meter` row in the `meters` table. So with this in mind, you can see that the declaration that a `meter` `has_many` `contracts` means that each one of those `meter` instances has many `contracts`.

Let's break this line down: `@customer.meters.contracts`

You have your `@customer` instance and you're asking it for all of its meters: `@customer.meters`. The return of that `meters` method is a collection of `meters` belonging to that `@customer`. Since it is the instance of a `meter` that has many contracts, you cannot ask the collection of meters for their contracts in that way.

You can ask it of an individual meter though: `@customer.meters.first.contracts` or you can iterate over all the meters and get all the contracts:

```
@customer.meters.flat_map(&:contracts) # => an array of all the contracts
```

Or, more generally, you might want to display a list of a customer's contracts in a view:

```
<% @customer.meters.each do |meter| %>
  <% meter.contracts.each do |contract|
    // display the contract
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

You can however, associate all the `contracts` to a `customer` through the `meters` association:

```
class Customer < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :meters, -> { includes :contracts }
  # ActiveRecord's shorthand declaration for associating
  # records through a join table, in this case 'meters'
  has_many :contracts, through: :meters
end
```

By adding that `has_many X, through: Y` you're saying that the customer record is associated to records in another table `X` by way of a join table `Y`.

With this, given a `customer` with existing `meters` and those meters having existing `contracts`, you'll be able to call `@customer.contracts` and ActiveRecord will fetch the `contracts` by joining the customer's `meters` with their `contracts` and return the `contracts` collection.

More about the Rails Has Many Through association: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association